# Микрофризы при ожидание коннекта по tcp в IEnumerator-е

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ожидаю подключение к tcp данным кодом:

```
foreach(var ip in _ips) {
        var cd = new CoroutineWithData(this, WaitConnect(ip));
        yield
        return cd.Coroutine;
        if (cd.Result != null) {
          //Отправляем данные
        }
}

private IEnumerator WaitConnect(string address) {
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    var parse = address.Split(':');
    var result = tcpClient.BeginConnect(parse[0], int.Parse(parse[1]), null, null);
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    yield
    return !tcpClient.Connected ? null : tcpClient;
}
```

Если подключение устанавливается - все хорошо.Однако если подключение не удается установить я получаю микрофризы на 1-3 секунды.Посоветуйте как от них возможно избавится

Comment: Смотря какую задачу вы решаете таким способом. Пока у вас получился синхронный код, который закономерно приводит задержкам. Опишите что вы хотите получить таким образом, возможно ваша задача решается иначе.

Comment: @rdorn нужно проверять может установлено ли соединение между клиентом и сервером

Comment: Да это понятно, не понятно для чего проверять и как часто это реально необходимо